# What is a regex to capture any strings that contain the @ symbol?

Tags: regex

What is a regex to capture any strings that contain the @ symbol?

For example, if you had the string...

```
Hey let's meet-up @5pm tonight.  E-mail me at joe@example.com.  What the !>?@## is your problem?
```

...the following would be returned:

```
@5pm 
joe@example.com. 
!>?@##
```

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Many languages support "string contains character" and "string contains substring" methods. In those that don't, it would probably be easier to do a string search rather than use a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

I won't write the regex for you but think about:

- Isolating the words, that is sequence of non-space characters terminated by a space (special case is the first and last word).
- Now a word that includes '@' = non-space* @ non-space*
- Allow zero or more words between words that include @

Now you should be able to write a regex in your favorite syntax...

Answer (score 1):

**[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)** will do what you want.

**\S - Matches any character that is not a whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).**

```
$subject = 'Hey let's meet-up @5pm tonight.  E-mail me at joe@example.com.  What the !>?@## is your problem?'

$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/\S*@\S*/', $subject, $matches)) {
    var_export($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => '@5pm',
    1 => 'joe@example.com.',
    2 => '!>?@##',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regular expression:

```
\S*@\S*
```

Quick test using JavaScript:

```
var text = "Hey let's meet-up @5pm tonight.  E-mail me at joe@example.com.  What the !>?@## is your problem?"
var re = /\S*@\S*/g
var matches = []
var match
while (match = re.exec(text)) matches.push(match[0])

console.log(matches) // ["@5pm", "joe@example.com.", "!>?@##"]
```

It shouldn't be difficult to write something similar in whichever language you're using.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid capturing a single '@': (\S*@\S+)|(\S+@\S*)